# How can I use a for loop to input values in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n,i,j  ;
char str[20][20]; 
printf("how many names?:");
scanf("%d",&n); 
 
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {

   printf("please enter name %d:",i+1);
   scanf("%s",str); 
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   int m=0;
   char str[i],ch,*s;
     printf("number of repeattetins of which leter in name %d do want:\n",i+1);
   s=str;
   ch=getche();
   while(*s)
      if(*s++==ch)
         m++; 
    printf("\n%d\n",m);
}

return 0;
}
```

In this program that I wrote, only the last input of my string enters the for loop, where is the problem? How do I enter array input in the for loop?

Comment: `scanf("%s", str)` should be `if(scanf(" %19s", str[i]) != 1) { something unexpected happened }`, at least.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Keep in mind that being new is *not relevant*; you should not tell us about this, or try to talk to us about things besides *the question*, in your question. These things are *at best* distracting (we want questions to be easy to read for future visitors, so that if they have the same problem, they can be helped as well), and at worst discourage you from improving yourself. Questions are closed or deleted based on the objective site standards - it is not useful to plead. I have edited your question to remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Multiple problems. At least: `scanf("%s",str);` needs to be `scanf("%s",str[i]);`. Also, `char str[i]` is shadowing the outer `str` variable which is not what you want to do. Remove that second `str` variable definition. Following that `s=str` should be `s=str[i];`

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with verbose warnings. It would have told you that the `scanf()` is wrong.

Comment: @Neil  Excuse me, can you explain more?

Comment: The [beginner's guide](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) has some useful infermation.

Comment: @kaylum   Thank you very much, my problem was solved.

Comment: @Neil  Thank you very much, my problem was solved